# set variable by using localstorage

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create the driver performance assistant.

when i start up the page it needs to read the variable from the last time and use that to count up.
(i have created a dashboard that reads data through a plugin from a game. i am trying to create the driver performance assistant from DAF (truck brand). the way it should work is when rolling out the vehicle it counts up a variable accordingly to the time it is rolling out (this part i have created and it works) now my problem is. i am also trying to save it in the localstorage so it wont get lost. but the variable is doing weird things when i tries to read the localstorage data.
this code only needs to be in javascript.

```
// variables for driver score
var startBrake = 0;
var endBrake = 0;
var timeDiffBrake = 0;
var countBrake = localStorage.getItem('brake');

var startRollout = 0;
var endRollout = 0;
var timeDiffRollout = 0;
var countRollout = localStorage.getItem('rollout');
```

```
    var speed = Math.abs(data.truck.speed > 0 ? Math.floor(data.truck.speed) : Math.round(data.truck.speed));
    var throttle = utils.formatFloat(data.truck.gameThrottle, 2);
    var serviceBrake = utils.formatFloat(data.truck.userBrake, 2);
    var retarder = data.truck.retarderBrake;
    var engineBrake = data.truck.motorBrakeOn;  
    var cruiseControl = data.truck.cruiseControlOn;
    var fuelConsumption = data.truck.fuelAverageConsumption * 100;
    
    // ANTICIPATE
    // Braking to long
    if (speed >= 50) {
        if (serviceBrake < 0.1) {
            startBrake = new Date();
        } else if (serviceBrake > 0.25) {
            endBrake = new Date();
            timeDiffBrake = (endBrake - startBrake) / 1000;
            if (timeDiffBrake > 5) {
                countBrake -= 0.01;
                // add "te lang remmen" display
            }
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('brake', countBrake);
    
    // Rolling out
    if (speed > 30 && speed < 89) {
        if (throttle > 0) {
            startRollout = new Date();
        } else if (throttle < 0.05 && serviceBrake == 0) {
            endRollout = new Date();
            timeDiffRollout = (endRollout - startRollout) / 1000;
            if (timeDiffRollout > 1) {
                countRollout += 0.01;
                // maybe add display
            }
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('rollout', countRollout);
    
    // EFFICIENT BRAKING
    var brake = localStorage.getItem('brake');
    var rollout = localStorage.getItem('rollout');
    var anticipate = brake + rollout;
    var efficientBraking = 0; // haven't done this yet
    
    var driverScore = Math.round((efficientBraking +  anticipate) / 2);
    data.drivingScorePercent = driverScore <= 0 ? 0 : driverScore >= 100 ? 100 : driverScore;
```

the main problem is this variable
var countRollout = localStorage.getItem('rollout');
it keeps saying my data is NAN (i think undefined)

i changed the lines to what "mister jojo" suggested but somehow i get some wierd data from the localstorage. i assumed that a "var += 0.01" would count 0.01 up but somehow it goes like this "0.010.010.010.010.01" instead of 0.01, 0.02, 0.03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are declaring the `countBrake` and `countRollout` variables, the value are `undefined` because you didn't set the values to `localStorage` yet. So, you can check whether there is already a value set in `localStorage` and set default value incase the value isn't set yet:

```
var countBrake = localStorage.getItem('brake') !== undefined ? localStorage.getItem('brake') : 0;

var countRollout = localStorage.getItem('rollout') !== undefined localStorage.getItem('rollout') : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

more simple for **Shuvo** answer is

with the use of the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
var countBrake   = localStorage.getItem('brake')   ?? 0
  , countRollout = localStorage.getItem('rollout') ?? 0
  ;
```